# Printf whitespace issues in C

Tags: c, printf, whitespace

I am doing a printf in C. Is there anyway I can do something like

```
printf("Display Menu
    1. Display all albums
    2. Display the tracks in an album
    0. Return to the main menu
    Please enter the choice:");
```

Getting the error

```
display.c:13: error: missing terminating " character
display.c:14: error: expected ')' before 'Display'
```

Any other ways this could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals can't span more than one line. You could use multiple `printf`s. Use `\n` to add newline characters at the end of each line.

```
printf("Display Menu\n");
printf("1. Display all albums\n");
printf("2. Display the tracks in an album\n");
printf("0. Return to the main menu\n");
printf("Please enter the choice:");
```

Or you could break the string up into multiple strings. This takes advantage of the C rule that adjacent string literals are combined into one: e.g., `"foo" "bar"` is equivalent to `"foobar"`.

```
printf("Display Menu\n"
       "1. Display all albums\n"
       "2. Display the tracks in an album\n"
       "0. Return to the main menu\n"
       "Please enter the choice:");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fputs(
    "Display Menu\n"
    "1. Display all albums\n"
    "2. Display the tracks in an album\n"
    "0. Return to the main menu\n"
    "Please enter the choice:\n", 
    stdout );
```

You can do exactly the same thing with `printf`, but as a matter of personal preference I like to use the simpler function since it is aesthetically appealing and more performant (at runtime, there's no need to parse a format string), although slightly less maintainable if a format string will need to be added.  Concatenating strings like this has been valid in C for a very long time, but some older implementations only allow a fairly short total string to be created.  The string in this example is not long enough to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Display Menu \n\t1. Display all albums \n\t2. Display the tracks in an album \n\t0. Return to the main menu \n\tPlease enter the choice:");
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can rewrite it to:

```
printf("Display Menu\n\t1. Display all albums\n\t2. Display the tracks in an album\n\t0. Return the main menu\n\tPlease enter the choice:");
```